# Decision/Logic tree behavior for solving integral convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, decision-trees

I'm trying to make a comprehensive decision tree for finding integral/improper integral convergence.
The goal would be a comprehensive "guide" or list to follow in order to determine the convergence without having these automatisms already learned.

Here is what I have made currently:

[Decision tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdr9C.png)

Are they any better ways of doing this? More optimized ? How can I make this tree more complete, more accurate ?

Apologies if language is off in the image, I'm not great at this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.